# Tab and Caps Lock won't show their icon in onboard keyboard

Tags: lubuntu, onboard

I'm customizing a Lubuntu for kiosk and I need a virtual keyboard software, I always install Onboard but I don't know yet what happened, this time the onboard won't appear caps lock and Tab keys.

Onboard version is 1.4.1-2ubuntu1, Lubuntu 18.04.3, but also updated it and this is happening in 18.04.5.

[image]

But there is a strange fact, I also have another virtual machine with Lubuntu 18.04.5 with the same Onboard version and it don't have any problem.

[image]

Comment: I would compare fonts between the two machines; it's possible a font used by the `onboard` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/onboard) exists on the second machine you have provided picture for, but not the first.. This is guess though

Comment: Okay, I will compare, I tried other fonts also but not worked, I also gave permission to /usr/share/onboard (or something like this) to user:user, but also didn't worked, I downloaded the iso for 18.04.5 and it also didn't worked, its very strange problem.

Comment: @guiverc, Fonts are okay, nothing missing.

Comment: You downloaded 18.04.5; how were you using it?  Was it being *tested* or *used* in *live* mode? and you had the issue occur?  (that is something I can quickly test; in fact booted 18.04.5 on a hp & dell box without issue)

Comment: Well, I just installed it to a VM in VMware Workstation 15 on my notebook and I also tested installing it to my computer with VMware Workstation 15 also.

Comment: Ive installed many times, from 18.04.3 and 18.04.5, I tried with minimal installation and also with full installation, with and without update at installation.

Comment: If I'd re-installed a different *bionic* ISO, I'd have opted for 18.04 or 18.04.1 (ie. an ISO that defaults to the GA kernel for the life of the product).  I found 2x pentium M boxes (thinkpads) that performed much better on GA kernel as they didn't like the 5.4 (that comes with HWE enabled or upgrade to 18.04.5; 18.04.3 was 5.0 kernel).  The picture looks like a theme that doesn't have an icon/pic for 21E5/21EA (meaning changing theme for onboard would fix if that's the issue)

Comment: About the theme, I already changed the theme and it still not working, about what you said, this is very suspicious, but I saw that after updated the Lubuntu was with HWE enabled, and where it was working, it was not with this HWE enabled, I will take a look at kernel versions.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  maybe useful in understanding the general (GA) and HWE kernel stacks.  The HWE changes (ie. allows 18.04 to use the 18.10 (4.18), 19.04 (5.0), 19.10 (5.3) and finally settle on the GA kernel for the next LTS release ie. 20.04 (5.4).  Kernel means kernel modules (ie. *drivers*) get changed too....